# Are there any data processing documentation tools?

Tags: python, data-engineering

I was responsible of generating a table report to a commercial area of my job. It is currently being updated daily by DAG in airtomation that runs a python script. The problem is that now I have to pass that responsability to someone else and the code is pretty extensive.

Are there any format or tool of documentation of data processing that you recommend? I'm trying a fluxogram but it cannot explain all the details that I wanted to include.